# App id for facebook like button for a page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I can't be signed out if I want to get a like button for a facebook page. Yet, if I sign in, generated code adds an "appid". It shows me a list of facebook apps but there's no choice for making a button NOT for one of those apps. I just want a button for a regular facebook company page.

Is this something new or a weird bug?

Using the code that this gives me, then throws a warning in console:

"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

This seems to imply that I need to make an app just to use a like button, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no alternative. You have to create a new app for this purpose. Or using app id of any of the existing app on that page will also work fine. Anyways all the apps on the page shares same page like.

Comment: Interesting, is this a new addition? I don't remember it being this way but I haven't grabbed a like button in good 6 months or more. Thanks for clearing this up for me.